# Getting no result when Serializing a Object using JsonConvert

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, json.net

This is my class :

```
class teacher_details_uploadable
    {
         string firstName;
         string lastName;
         string contactNumber;
         string emailaddress;
        List<string> classes_names = new List<string>();
        List<all_class_details> all_the_classes_under_teacher = new List<all_class_details>();
        public teacher_details_uploadable()
        {
            firstName = Teacher.FirstName;
            lastName = Teacher.Lastname;
            contactNumber = Teacher.Contactnumber;
            emailaddress = Teacher.Emailaddress;
            classes_names = Teacher.Classes_Names;
            all_the_classes_under_teacher = Teacher.All_the_classes_under_teacher;
        }
    }
```

Code for converting its object into text:

```
teacher_details_uploadable teacher = new teacher_details_uploadable();
            var text=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(teacher);
```

But in text i get this {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a blank text json object because none of your properties are public. By default they are internal, and will not be serialized.

Answer (score 3):

**Json.NET's** default behavior only processes fields that are public. So change your non-public fields like so:

```
 public string firstName;
 public string lastName;
 public string contactNumber;
 public string emailaddress;
 ...
```

Another work around, if you're unable publicize the fields, is to use the ***JsonProperty*** attribute of Json.Net as shown below:

```
class teacher_details_uploadable
    {    [JsonProperty]
         string firstName;
         [JsonProperty]
         string lastName;
         [JsonProperty]
         string contactNumber;
         [JsonProperty]
         string emailaddress;
         ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Properties and fields need to be public for JsonConvert to be able to serialize them. I.e. `string firstName;` should be `public string firstName;`. If you cannot make these fields public consider using a custom [Converter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm).